# How do I develop templates for cloud automation manager?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-automation-manager

I am using the Bluemix Cloud Automation Manager to deploy application resources on AWS. I have tried out the existing templates and I would like to develop my own because the existing templates do not include the application I would like to install. How do I develop my own templates? The documentation explains how to deploy a pre-existing template but not how to develop a custom one.

[Deploying Templates](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudAutomationManager/cam_deploying.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Automation Manager (CAM) uses Terraform to define and provision cloud infrastructure.  Today, CAM includes the community providers for AWS and VMWare and a custom provider for IBM Cloud.  You can write your own Terraform configurations and it's pretty straight forward to just import them into CAM and use them.  It's worth mentioning that the sample templates in CAM are under the Apache License 2.0.  They can easily be modified and reused.